# LWJGL 3D collision Detection

Tags: java, 3d, lwjgl, collision

I have a promblem with my 3D collision detection, here is the code:

```
    private void checkHit() {

   if(ishitable){   

    if(pos.x-xscale < TimeToKill.player.position.x){
        if(TimeToKill.player.position.x > pos.x){
            if(TimeToKill.player.position.y < pos.y){
                if( TimeToKill.player.position.y > pos.y-yscale){
                    if( TimeToKill.player.position.z > pos.z-zscale){

                       if(TimeToKill.player.position.z < pos.z){
                       System.out.println("HIT!" + pos + TimeToKill.player.position);
            }

        }}
    }

}}
}
```

So it doesen´t works fine, it says HIT!, just when I am standing next to a Entity (it is a cube, so nothing big).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second condition is wrong. First line:

```
pos.x - xscale < TimeToKill.player.position.x
```

Second line is equivalent to:

```
pos.x < TimeToKill.player.position.x
```

So you need to flip the comparison. You should really refactor this into a `hitTest` method or something. Your current code is really verbose and confusing.

Comment: It has been the result of much testing, Normaly my code isnt confused. Thanks for your help.